# Remote GUI login from Windows machine to Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Linux server from Windows machine in graphical mode via SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50727/accessing-linux-server-from-windows-machine-in-graphical-mode-via-ssh)

How I can login to a remote CentOS' GUI from my Windows 7 laptop?

Comment: Try a VNC server/client.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `vnc-server` on your Centos Machine. A very good document can be found on the CentOS wiki http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server

Also, you can get an Xserver like http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

This would allow you to connect to your CentOS machine's X server and display a window (or smaller windows) on your Windows host.